# Quarkus and Hibernate Orm : Entity manager is null

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

I'am doing the test project tutorial to understand quarkus and hibernate

https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm

here is the project : https://github.com/bussiere/quarkusorm

My question is, it seems that i've followed the tutorial,and the orm injection here hibernate seems to not working and i'am asking myself why.

So here is my GretingRessource :

```
package babylon;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.PathParam;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import serialiazer.CustomMsgSerializer;
import EntityObject.Gift;
import serialiazer.CustomGiftSerializer;
import EntityManager.SantaClausService;


@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    public class Msg {
        public String msg;
    }
    static ObjectMapper objectMapperMsg = new ObjectMapper();
    static SimpleModule moduleMsg =
            new SimpleModule("CustomMsgSerializer", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));

    static ObjectMapper objectMapperGift = new ObjectMapper();
    static SimpleModule moduleGift =
            new SimpleModule("CustomGiftSerializer", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));

    static SantaClausService santaClausService = new SantaClausService();


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/hello")
    public String hello() throws JsonProcessingException {
        moduleMsg.addSerializer(Msg.class, new CustomMsgSerializer());
        objectMapperMsg.registerModule(moduleMsg);


        // as json now return "Hello from RESTEasy Reactive";
        Msg msg = new Msg();
        msg.msg = "bonjour";
        return objectMapperMsg.writeValueAsString(msg);
    }

    // get gift by id
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/gift/{id}/")
    public String getGiftById(@PathParam("id")String id) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Gift gift = santaClausService.getGiftById(Long.parseLong(id));


        return "{}";

    }
}
```

My santaclausservice :

```
package EntityManager;

import EntityObject.Gift;
// import hibernate ApplicationScoped
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
// import hibernate EntityManager
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
// import hibernate Inject
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
// import hibernate Transactional
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;

@ApplicationScoped
public class SantaClausService {
    @Inject
    EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void createGift(String giftDescription) {
        Gift gift = new Gift();
        gift.setName(giftDescription);
        em.persist(gift);
    }

    // get gift by id
    public Gift getGiftById(Long id) {
        return em.find(Gift.class, id);
    }
}
```

And the gift object :

```
package EntityObject;

// import hibernate Entity annotation


import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator;


@Entity
public class Gift {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "giftSeq", sequenceName = "gift_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "giftSeq")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is the error :

```
2024-03-15 13:33:03,645 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) HTTP Request to /hello/gift/1/ failed, error id: 7f3acd91-e27d-4ccc-8825-e0b77611a7a8-1: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jakarta.persistence.EntityManager.find(java.lang.Class, Object)" because "this.em" is null
    at EntityManager.SantaClausService.getGiftById(SantaClausService.java:27)
    at babylon.GreetingResource.getGiftById(GreetingResource.java:54)
    at babylon.GreetingResource$quarkusrestinvoker$getGiftById_34dc4182bd60f7cecc9aa5403f2e730dc93616e1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
```

Regards

Comment: `GreetingResource#santaClausService` must be `@Inject`-ed

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci how ?

Comment: before use Quarkus Hibernate support will be useful read how cdi works (https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi)

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci i will read this again and read this but in the link you gave me there was no how to inject part but thanks

Comment: `@Inject GreetingResource santaClausService;` in `GreetingResource` instead of use the new operator.

Comment: thanks it was @Inject  SantaClausService santaClausService; but thanks a lot it worked

Comment: Best that is added an answer so future readers don't have to read through comments